# How to Intercept and Modify XHR?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I read several answers about this question but I could not understand what I'm doing wrong. I wanted to be able to intercept and modify the requests and responses. The requests I get. The responses is not.

The response of the request is a json I just wanted to be able to modify the urls of the response before arriving in the application

```
 <script>
   let oldXHROpen = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

   window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
       if (url.startsWith("http://example.com")) {
            url = url.replace("http://example.com", "https://site2.com");      
        } else if (url.startsWith("http://") || url.startsWith("https://")) {
            // do nothing with the url
        } else if (url.startsWith("//")) {
           url = "https:" + url;
        } else if (url.startsWith("/")) {
            url = "https://site2.com" + url;    
        } else if (url.startsWith(".")) {
            url = "https://site2.com" + url.replace("./", "/");     
        } else {
            url = "https://site2.com" + url;
        }

        // This should take care of the response but it is not working.
        this.addEventListener('load', function() {
            var original_response, modified_response;

            original_response = this.responseText;
            Object.defineProperty(this, "responseText", {writable: true});

            modified_response = JSON.parse(original_response);
            modified_response.htmlinfo = "woops! All data has gone!";
            this.responseText = JSON.stringify(modified_response);
       });

       return oldXHROpen.apply(this, arguments);
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `Object.defineProperty(this, "responseText", {writable: true});` works? Try verifying that part.

Comment: This seems to be right. What do you think should be different?

Comment: How exactly is not working? Does the code in the `load` event handler run? Does the property descriptor look as expected in the result handler? Can you please post a [mcve]?